# Groovy: Named parameter constructors

Tags: groovy

I found really cool that one can do:

```
class Foo {
    String name
}

def foo = new Foo(name:"Test")
```

But, it only works when my file name matches the class name. If I have a file with a bunch of classes like:

```
class AllClassesInOneFile {
    class Bar {}
    class Foo {
      String name
    }
}

def foo = new Foo(name:"Test")
```

Now, it does not work anymore I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments

I wonder if it is still possible to invoke named parameter argument style with scripts and nested classes.

Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like Groovy needs explicit reference to an instance of the outer class:

```
class Baz {
    class Bar {}
    class Foo {
      String name
    }
}

def baz = new Baz()

def f = new Baz.Foo(baz, [name: "john doe"])

assert f.name == "john doe"
```

Comment: That's right, and it kinda sucks :(. I'm sure the groovy developers have a ton of reasons for that. But I found out that not only named parameters do not work. Any constructor won't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FuriousBob If you make your nested classes static you should be able to create them without creating an instance of the outer class.

Answer (score 2):

Non-static nested object can't exist without instance of the outer class.
The same in java.
Just change nested object to static.